# LINQ ToDictionary System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.'

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, linq-to-sql

Going bonkers here, but have a LINQ query that i want to convert to a Dictionary object, but getting a "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.'" error when doing so, so I'm stumped. It only happens if I just want to use the Key and use a Product class as the value.

```
ProductsDataContext context = new ProductsDataContext();

Dictionary<int, Product> result = context.Products.Where(x => x.ProductName.StartsWith("N")).ToDictionary(x => x.Prod_ID);
```

The Prod_ID is an integer in the class and in the database. Nowhere should be converted to a string, so I'm stumped as to this error message.

If I write it something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> result = context.Products.Where(x => x.ProductName.StartsWith("N")).ToDictionary(x => x.Prod_ID, x=> x.ProductName)
```

It works fine and there is no data conversion error message (the Key is an integer as specified). I hadn't used this method before (w/LINQ to SQL), so I'm thinking that something is missing. (It works on non-SQL stuff)

Tried the same code on a different table and have gotten results (no errors).
Looks like the problem was with nulls in the Product table (varchar() nulls - so the error message is completely off - a bug, perhaps?)

```
    StylesDataContext context = new StylesDataContext();

    Dictionary<int,Style> results = context.Styles.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.style_name.EndsWith("d")).ToDictionary(x => x.style_id);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Style> r in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id: " + r.Key.ToString()  + "\tName: " + r.Value.style_name + "\tGUID: " + r.Value.style_bvin  );
    }
```

Comment: Its possible one of your variables in `Product` is an int but linq tries to convert it to string? I had similar problems with boolean from a mysql database (it stores them as 1 and 0, usually its fine but with some linq queries it refuses to do the conversion correctly)

Comment: I suspect that using `ToList()` instead of `ToDictionary` will cause the same error in your first query. If this is true, you have an error in a mapping definition.

Comment: Try followng : Dictionary<int, List<Product>> result = context.Products.GroupBy(x => x.ProductName.Substring(0,1)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Prod_ID.ToList());  Three things wrong. 1) Your key is a string not an integer since it starts with a Letter. 2)  Since more than one Product can start with N your dictionary is a list. 3) You use GroupBy when building a dictionary

Comment: The key is an integer (and mapped as such) in the DB and DBML (it was auto-generated, but I verified it is).
I'm not doing any type of grouping - the inner query returns a single list of Product. Not sure what you mean by grouping in this case.

I simply want the prod_ID to be the Key and the Product object to be the Value.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
ProductsDataContext context = new ProductsDataContext();
var r1 = context.Products.Where(x => x.ProductName.StartsWith("N"));
var r2 = r1.ToDictionary(x => x.Prod_ID);
```

Does the error occur for r1 or r2?  If you are using VS hold over the variable name to see what type is being used for each var statement.  It would seem possible that the Enumerable for Products may be generating the error.

Comment: 2nd line generates the error.
Now my first version is generating the error. <head scratch>
.ToDictionary(x => x.Prod_ID, x=> x.ProductName )   <- this worked just fine an hour ago (?)  Maybe my db is offline.

Comment: OK. I picked a different table and the query basically works as written, the only difference in the new table is there are no nulls anywhere. The other table had nulls in some varchar() columns from the rows retrieved.

Comment: Is it possible that the ProductName property is the root of the problem?  I'm thinking someone coded it as "return letter + (string) number" where "number" is prototyped as object.  Also I don't know how active you db is but when trying to pen a problem like this down, you should try to use static data to reduce the run to run variation.

Comment: I created a new Product2 table and copied all the data from the Product table into it, then tried again. 
The query works w/o the error. Identical tables, constraints, everything. 
For kicks, I tried the old query again, and it failed.
Then, I deleted the original dbml file, and added it back - the old query does not generate an error anymore. So, somehow, the original,  unedited, autogenerated DBML file corrupted itself!  UGH!

Comment: Well I guess if it "ain't" the code it must be the data :-)
Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this particular question is that, somehow, Visual Studio 2017 corrupted a portion of the auto-generated code (I made no changes what-so-ever) for the LINQ-to-SQL classes. Deleting these classes and adding them back solved the problem regarding the error message for this query.

My presumption that the data was corrupt or nulls were present in the table  causing the problem was incorrect.

I ran a harddrive scan to see if data was corrupted via my PC, but it came back clean.

If this happens again, I will be sure to run a full file-by-file comparison to see what portion was actually corrupted and post it here and to the MS Dev team. If this is a bug, it's a terrible, time-wasting, one.